# NSFetchedResultsController (and UITableView) delegate methods calls growing and growing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Setup: UITableView with FRC. Rows are simple list of text content user can pull to refresh to get the latest.

I’m seeing strange behavior where cellForRow is called for each row, multiple times. So I see it for 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 (visible rows), but these 4 rows all have cellForRow called multiple times. But the first time you view the list they're called once. The second time, twice, etc. By the 7th time, after the user sees the content, behind the scenes it continues to try and configure the cell over and over and eventually crashes.

So if you go to any list of content, it hits the server, downloads the stories, creates NSMOs and displays. In the logs, I see configureCell called once for each visible row. If I refresh, I see the same. BUT if i navigate to a different screen, then come back, when I pull to refresh I notice that cellforrow is called twice for each row. If I continue this process of leaving and coming back, every time I do, cellforrow is called an additional time. Logging some of the fetched results controller delegate methods, I see willchangecontent before each set of cellforrow calls. Can someone help me determine why my cellforrow method is called a growing number of times?

One idea was the way I was setting up FRC. I followed code like CoreDataBooks and moved things to viewdidload, but still seeing issue.

I have a property in the .h and in the .m have what i thought was a standard setup:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
//NSLog(@"fetchedresulscontroller");
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
{
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

// initialize fetch request. setup predicate, sort, etc.

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

// perform actual fetch. delegate methods take it from here
NSError *fetchError = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&fetchError])
{
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", fetchError, [fetchError userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with when you run your `NSFetchedResultsController`? Which TVC lifecycle method is it in?

Comment: So do you have a local variable that persists the FRC in memory? Also when do you set the FRC - that is - which part of your code does this occur?

Comment: i have a property and then set the FRC in - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController which posted above. thanks!

Comment: you're correct. self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController is only place i set it. and yes, i then use it in something like numberOfSections like this: return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]; this confirm your suspicions? thanks so much

Comment: So I usually set my local property for a FRC in my `viewDidLoad` TVC lifecycle method. Try that and see if that assists...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89112/discussion-between-skinsfan00atg-and-andrewbuilder).

Comment: @skinsfan00atg Are you able to share more of your code or recreate this behavior in a skeleton project? I'm not seeing any issue with code that you've posted thus far, so I suspect the culprit is lurking somewhere less obvious.

Comment: @emb absolutely! I'm happy to send anything, just wasn't sure how to do that on here. the file in question is pretty long, but I'm happy to share whatever would help

Comment: @skinsfan00atg If you want to share multiple files, I think your best bet would be to create a repository and share the URL here. If you just want to send the contents of a single file, [Gists](https://gist.github.com) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) are a couple of good choices.

Comment: I think it would be easier to get more help, if you could post more of your code in the question.

Comment: thanks guys! i just cracked it this morning and will post answer for anyone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

andrewbuilder was on the right track. It all had to do with the FRC, but the trick was the third party SWReveal library used for the menu. Turns out, I was creating a new VC each time (previous wasn't deallocated) and the FRC was looking at all live view controllers. So each time i tapped a selection from the menu, another was added and the config calls were called for that.

The solution is to nil out the FRC delegate in viewwilldisappear and set it in viewwillappear